# Does a user need to be the Account Owner to add Opportunity Team Members

Tags: sharing, opportunity

I am trying to use standard Opportunity Team Member functionality and it doesn't seem to match the documentation.

I have the following sharing model

```
account: public read/write
opportunity: private
```

To add an opportunity team member it appears that the user needs to be the owner of the account (or a sys admin) rather than just the owner of the opportunity. From the docs:

> Only members with read access to the associated account can be added to the opportunity team unless you have the “Modify All Data” permission or are the account owner or above the account owner in the role hierarchy. [Adding Opportunity Team Members](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=salesteam_add.htm&language=en_US)

Since accounts are public read/write every user already has read access to the account but this is what seems to be causing the issue.

Comment: I just tested this in my developer org. I set the sharing model the same as you and was able to create an opp owned by someone other than the account owner and then add someone to the opp team. What is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, there was a bug in Winter '13 that would only allow the Account Owner to add members to Opportunity Team. This was listed on the Known Issues site (http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SU3hAAG) but should have been fixed since about two weeks.

Please give it another try and I think you will be happily surprised. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have exp on this, but: reading the [FAQ](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=salesteam_def.htm&language=en_US) it says:

> You can't use opportunity teams for private opportunities

Maybe change the global rule for opptys would solve this?

I also don't think you need to be the account owner, you just need to be the account owner, or higher in the role hierarchy for that account.

> Owner of opportunity record, or above owner in your organization's role hierarchy

Comment: No, I can create opportunity team members if the running user is the owner of the account AND the owner of the opportunity. However, if the running user is just the owner of the opportunity it fails.